# Non-existent jar resources in Java eclipse

Tags: java, jar

In eclipse, when using an external jar (SuperCSV in particular) I get an error which reads: "variable references non-existent resource". The build path has the Jar added to it and does not display any errors until run. Also the error seems to only occur when java RMI is used (commenting out the RMI code allows the code to run, just without actual functionality).

Google searches have not been helpful, so hopefully someone here can help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check your resource path and make sure that the relative workspace location is the same place as where your project lives. Otherwise, it may not work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify your ant classpath by going to "Window->References->Ant->Runtime->Classpath". Adding or removing the jar you have problem with here.