# How to run & debug multiple java programs with one Ant buildfile on seperate consoles in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ant, launch

I'm working on an application for my distributed system laboratory course. I have a working ant buildfile that runs multiple targets. My modus operandi currently is to open terminal  windows (linux) and run separate ant targets.(with a Logger) 
what i would need is the possibility to:

- run and debug the project with the ant buildfile in eclipse
- open multiple eclipse consoles (or maybe eclipse remote systems - local shells), one per ant target

i found a very good answer/solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/316783

but i didn't get it all together. i read the oracle tut for jar file creation and tried to write a manifest file, i guess creating a java launcher is really basic knowledge, 
but it didn't work.

could someone please describe, how to implement the solution by "VonC" in detail (https://stackoverflow.com/q/316783) or share a better/similar/more "simple" one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create your own jar. What the solution is talking about is setting up an Eclipse launcher from an ant target.

A tutorial on how to set it up:
http://individual.utoronto.ca/kia/

Comment: thanks for the fast feedback. i now have a new run configuration with: Main class: org.apache.tools.ant.Main
VM arguments: 
-Dant.home=${resource_loc:/usr/lib/eclipse} 
-f ${workspace_loc:/VerSysA1/build.xml}
(program args are defined in the buildfile)
and  classpath user entries:
ant.jar / ant-launcher,jar before default classpath.
the only problem now is this error log:
Variable references non-existent resource : ${resource_loc:/usr/lib/eclipse} org.eclipse.debug.core
(i even tried referencing the libraries manually) how could that be?
any suggestions?

Comment: maybe i should add that i checked in advance that the jar is really at this location.

Comment: Try the solution proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263765/non-existent-jar-resources-in-java-eclipse) for the error you are receiving.